# Python 2.7.6 - UnicodeEncodeError in Sublime 2 but NO error in Terminal

Tags: python, macos, unicode, terminal

I have a script that reads from a website. The website has thai characters.

When I run the script in the Terminal, it prints the text fine.

When I run the script in the Sublime 2 (cmd+B) I get:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have googled and read but nothing seems to work. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sublime Text 2 command window apparently encodes Unicode strings as `ascii` before outputting them if they don't have an encoding attached.

Test case that runs in Terminal, but fails to run under Sublime Cmd+B:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print u'Hello 漢字!'
```

Encoding the `unicode` object when printing it works around this for me:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print u'Hello 漢字!'.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Sometimes, though, I get some repeated or partially repeated output saying `[Decode error - output not utf-8]`. Re-running it shows the correct strings though. Like 75/25 works/breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Try   File-> Save With Encoding -> UTF-8 and run it again. This should work.

Comment: This did not work unfortunately. The other answer in this Q did, however.